# Titanium ScrollView - Not scroll the first part in scrollView?

Tags: titanium, scrollview

I need to have a view on the top in my ScrollView, who not scroll with the table view when scroll down. But follow the table when scroll vertical.

I have tried to put scrollView nestlet in another scrollView, but simulator crasch on that.

Is there any who knowes a solution on this??

Comment: Could you prepare some image which scroll should be scrollable and which not on different gestures? Also your current code could be helpful to understand what you tried to achieve.

Comment: The thing is that I havnt begin on any code cuz I dont know really how to begin.

I want som title stay on the top when I scroll down, but this title shoult follow the column with when I scroll to the right and left.
I would also like to have same on the left side, its stay when I scroll left and right, but scroll with the tableview when I scroll up and down.
Like spreadsheet but the left and top columns stay when skrolling the content.

I have the picture in my mind only. I hope you understand. Sorry that I cant get you more..

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea. See if it help.

Add the title view to the Window but not the scrollView or tableView.

Then listen to the Scroll event of the scrollView or tableView, and add code to do the re-positioning of the title view in the event handler.